# How can one pass a variant argument to DBUS method call in C++?

Tags: c++, dbus, variant

For DBUS methods such as

`org.freedesktop.DBUS.Properties.Set(string,string,A Value)`

which takes "any valid DBus type" as its third argument, this argument's DBUS type (i.e. BOOLEAN) has to be wrapped in a variant.

There aren't many clear examples on the web on how to do this.  How does one create this variant in C++ without using the dbus-c++ library?

Comment: Good info but not exactly a question.  Maybe make the question 'how do you wrap a value in a variant?' and answer it with the code. [Share your knowledge Q&A style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if it was bad form to just post, but I wanted to share the info.  Now I know for future epiphanies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out.

You can do this by using the functions:

```
DBusMessageIter iter,subIter;

//append arguments to the Set() method. (string interface, string property, value)
dbus_message_iter_init_append(msg, &iter);

dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&iter, DBUS_TYPE_STRING,&interfaceString);
dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&iter, DBUS_TYPE_STRING,&propertyString);

//HOW TO CALL VARIANT?:
dbus_message_iter_open_container(&iter, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT, DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN_AS_STRING, &subIter);
dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&subIter, DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN, &valBOOL);
dbus_message_iter_close_container(&iter, &subIter);
```

In this example, the third argument is DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN in string form. &valBool is of type `dbus_bool_t`.

Hope it helps someone.